# Can you pass through Stansted security any time of day/night?

Tags: airports, airport-security, opening-hours, stn

According to the website:

- The airport is open 24h
- Only 24h coffee shop is located *after* security

Can I infer that it is possible to pass through security at any point in a 24h period? Or do you have to go through before the last flight, if wishing to stay there for a morning flight?

Answer (score 6):

I speak from memory about 1 year ago.

At 1 am (the time I got to the airport) the security area was closed. There were many people sleeping on the floor inside the airport. At around 4 am the security area reopened. The cleaners started work around this time, so those who were still sleeping were woken up.

Anyway, there was a 24 hour bar pre-security, located just outside the toilets.